# Copy sheet from closed workbook to active workbook sheet with explanation

Tags: excel, vba, import, copy-paste

I know this is probably very basic but I cannot find a consistent code which works.

I am trying to copy the first and only sheet in a closed file on a shared drive location into the first sheet of the active workbook from which I want to run the macro from.

If anyone can please share any help with an explanation of the code of the steps that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Note: You will need to open the closed workbook to be able to access it's sheets - A quick google should yield a bunch of results on how to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks - I am still quite new to VBA and have tried googling but it yields so many different methods which I have failed to make work, hence why I tried posting on this forum. Happy to learn by doing but not sure if you can point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Here are a few links to get you in the right direction - be sure to read the documentation and if you get stuck, google *that* problem (and ask a *specific* question here if it's still unclear). These will follow the basic flow your code should follow: [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open), [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange) and [Range Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

Comment: Do a bit of trial and error with each of those one by one, then build your application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA to copy and paste as values from a closed workbook to an active workbook, Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362064/excel-vba-to-copy-and-paste-as-values-from-a-closed-workbook-to-an-active-workbo) (though it states MAC OS X it is the same code for Windows)

Comment: Yes it does - thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One of the most useful features for VBA Excel programmers is the `Excel macro recorder`. I frequently use the recorder to learn how Excel would write code to implement actions that I take via mouse clicks and menu selections.

Cut to the chase.  Suppose my source workbook is called katy_movies.xlsx and contains a list of viewed/favorite movie titles and various cell formatting.  Suppose I have that spreadsheet open and want to copy and paste it (with source formatting retained) into a blank worksheet in a different workbook.  Here's **almost** the entire code that the macro recorder "wrote" based on my mouse clicks and menu selections (I made 2 adjustments).

**Note:**  my original solution failed to open the closed source workbook.  Here is code that does that and, as a bonus, closes the source after the copy/paste operation:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro  (recorded by excel macro recorder)
'
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="\path\to\katy_movies.xlsx"
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    Macro3
    Windows("katy_movies.xlsx").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate
    Range("A1").Select      ' I manually added this line to ensure a valid paste locn
                            ' for an entire worksheet
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select      ' Manually added this line to unselect all cells following
                            ' paste operation.

    Range("A1").Copy        ' Effectively empty clipboard to stop Excel from whining
                            ' about the next Close operation.
    Windows("katy_movies.xlsx").Close  ' close the briefly opened spreadsheet

    ' force focus back to original worksheet
    Windows("Book1").Activate
End Sub
```

I can't stress enough the usefulness of the macro recorder....

Comment: Not a bad answer (very helpful imo) but it's missing a key section of the question - *I am trying to copy the first and only sheet in a **closed file**...*. Your answer doesn't address this and as such doesn't really answer the question!

Comment: Updated code to open a closed workbook.